# Need Multiple instances to be launched for different environments using one AWS CloudFormation Template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I'm have a requirement to build 3 different types of environment each having different numbers of instances to be launched using single CF template in JSON. For example: 1st ENV needs 2 instances, 2nd ENV needs 4 instances and 3rd ENV needs 8 instances. Please advice

im getting input from user to choose the ENV type and based on that the number of instances should be launched.

unable to mention instance count under EC2 properties and unable to use Fn::If to change the condition

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a cloudformation parameter for the instance count?

Comment: You can also use a Mapping of env to instance count to solve this.

Comment: This is an interview question? If not, why the restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Mappings** in conjunction with **Parameters** as following:

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "ALB and ASG",
"Mappings": {
    "Environment": {
        "i": {
            "InstanceType": "t2.small",
            "Count": 2
        },
        "s": {
            "InstanceType": "t3.small",
            "Count": 3
        },
        "p": {
            "InstanceType": "m1.small",
            "Count": 4
        }
    }
},
"Parameters": {
    "ShortEnv": {
        "AllowedValues": [
            "i",
            "p",
            "s"
        ],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must define the current environment",
        "Description": "Environment type",
        "Type": "String"
    }
}
```

And then can use it as following in the relevant resource properties:

```
"InstanceType": {
    "Fn::FindInMap": [
        "Environment",
        {
            "Ref": "ShortEnv"
        },
        "InstanceType"
    ]
},
"DesiredCapacity": {
    "Fn::FindInMap": [
        "Environment",
        {
            "Ref": "ShortEnv"
        },
        "InstanceType"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @gopi-r If this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.